# Cannot create field catalog with REUSE_ALV_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE

Tags: abap

I'm new to ABAP, and I'm trying to build a field catalog using the `REUSE_ALV_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE` function module. This function module exits with `sy-subrc` value `1` ("Inconsistent interface") and a message dialog appears saying that the field catalog couldn't be build.

My code is the same as the examples found online. Maybe I missed something.

My program consists of a TOP include, a FORMS include and the main module:

**FORMS** include:

```
FORM DISPLAY_WITH_ALV_LIST.

CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE'
  EXPORTING
    I_PROGRAM_NAME               = sy-repid
    I_INTERNAL_TABNAME           = 'it_report'
    I_INCLNAME                   = sy-repid
  CHANGING
    CT_FIELDCAT                  = it_fldcat.

CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_LIST_DISPLAY'
  EXPORTING
    IT_FIELDCAT                    = it_fldcat
  TABLES
    T_OUTTAB                       = it_report.

ENDFORM.

FORM ZSELECT.
  SELECT   VBELN ERDAT ERNAM
    FROM   VBAK
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE it_report
    WHERE  ERDAT IN S_ERDAT
    AND    ERNAM IN S_ERNAM.
ENDFORM.
```

**TOP** include:

```
TYPE-POOLS: slis.
TABLES VBAK.

DATA: BEGIN OF it_report OCCURS 0,
  VBELN LIKE VBAK-VBELN,
  ERDAT LIKE VBAK-ERDAT,
  ERNAM LIKE VBAK-ERNAM,
END OF it_report.

DATA it_fldcat TYPE slis_t_fieldcat_alv.
```

**Main module:**

```
REPORT  ZMLA_EXO1.

INCLUDE ZMLA_EXO1_TOP.
INCLUDE ZMLA_EXO1_SCREEN.
INCLUDE ZMLA_EXO1_FORM.

INITIALIZATION.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN.

START-OF-SELECTION.

PERFORM ZSELECT.
PERFORM DISPLAY_WITH_ALV_LIST.

END-OF-SELECTION.
```

Comment: it_report should be in capital => IT_REPORT. i_inclname = sy-repid => this is wrong, as sy-repid will be the main program, but as far as I remember (don't have system access right now) this line can be commented out

Comment: I did as you said but the error message still shows up.

Comment: replace the LIKEs with TYPEs in the internal table declaration. And the internal table is declared the old (very old way (OCCURS), this should also be replaced with TYPE declaration and the internal table declaration based on the TYPE

Comment: Using TYPE instead of LIKE didn't change the error message.

Comment: If I make a TYPE declaration and base the internal table on it (removing OCCURS), I can't SELECT .. INTO it: I get the following message at activation: "IT_REPORT" is not an internal table "OCCURS n" specification is missing.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently the code you indicate doesn't produce the error you mention (therefore we can't help you efficiently). Note that the function modules `REUSE_ALV_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE` and `REUSE_ALV_LIST_DISPLAY` are obsolete and there's no investment on them anymore by SAP. Instead, use the class `CL_SALV_TABLE`.

Comment: I've edited the FORMS include, which lacked the ZSELECT form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise using the "SALV" class. It's pretty straight forward, in your case it would look like this:

```
    DATA: go_salv_table TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table.

    CALL METHOD cl_salv_table=>factory
      IMPORTING
        r_salv_table = go_salv_table
      CHANGING
        t_table      = it_report.
    go_salv_table->display( ).
```

If you still insist on using the function module (FM) `REUSE_ALV_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE`, and generate field catalog from internal table, then these conditions must be observed:

1. Your internal table with the data to be displayed has to be declared with the word "`OCCURS`" (not a must to use addition "`WITH HEADER LINE`").
2. Fields of the internal table have to be declared using "`LIKE`". It will not work if you use "`TYPE`" to declare the fields.
3. No line in your program should exceed 72 characters. Otherwise a short dump will be generated with the exception `cx_sy_read_src_line_too_long` since the FM has to scan your program code looking for the internal table definition.

In short, it's an old FM with a lot of problems.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Two questions: what does the go_ prefix stand for ? And how can I get rid of "OCCURS n" from it_report ? If I remove it I get an error about incompatibility of type between it_report and t_table from the factory method.

Comment: 1. go_ : this is just naming convention for "global object". It sometimes varies from project to project, some people use gr_  "global_reference".

Comment: 2. To get rid of "OCCURS" and if you are using "SALV" method. I would define my table like this:  `TYPES: BEGIN OF is_report,  vbeln TYPE vbak-vbeln,  erdat TYPE vbak-erdat,  ernam TYPE vbak-ernam,  END OF is_report.  DATA: it_report TYPE TABLE OF is_report.`  Copy the code and paste in abap editor, use pretty printer to format.

Comment: Thank you ! It works (I used LIKE instead of TYPE).